# Geosparql with Protege and Parliament

Tags: sparql, protege

I am very new with GeoSPARQL.  I downloaded the ontology, imported it in Protégé and created classes and individual following [Appendix B in GeoSPARQL user guide (PDF)](https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=47664).

1. When using Parliament to ask for WKT, the values are being duplicated which is not happening in Protégé:

   ```
   SELECT ?geom 
   WHERE {
       ?x my:exactGeometry ?xGeom .
       ?xGeom geo:asWKT ?geom .
   }
   ```

   The result is showing every value 2 times.
2. I am not getting any results when executing `geof:sf` functions.

Comment: Do you mean that you're not getting results for `geof:sf` functions when querying with Parliament or with Protégé?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used GeoSPARQL, so I can't address much of that, but, to the first point, a query like

```
SELECT ?geom WHERE {
    ?x my:exactGeometry ?xGeom .
    ?xGeom geo:asWKT ?geom .
}
```

will, by default, return one value for `?geom` for each way that the graph pattern can match.  E.g., if the graph contains

```
_:x1 my:exactGeometry _:xGeom1 .
_:xGeom1 geo:asWKT _:geom .
_:x2 my:exactGeometry _:xGeom2 .
_:xGeom2 geo:asWKT _:geom .
```

so that there are two patterns that match (one with `?x = _:x1` and `?xGeom = _:xGeom1`, and the other with `?x = _:x2` and `?xGeom = _:xGeom2`), you'll see `_:geom` in the results twice.  You can remove these kinds of duplicates using `distinct` in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?geom WHERE {
    ?x my:exactGeometry ?xGeom .
    ?xGeom geo:asWKT ?geom .
}
```

To the second point, as I mentioned, I am not GeoSPARQL user, but I suspect that the specification merely *defines* what these extension functions should do.  Unless you've downloaded some code (e.g., a Protégé plugin), I don't see where the implementation of these functions would have been provided.  SPARQL extensions must be provided by the SPARQL endpoint implementation;  they aren't defined in the ontologies that you download or the data over which you query.  The Wikipedia article on GeoSPARQL has an [Implementations section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoSPARQL#Implementation) which lists three implementations that support GeoSPARQL.  One of these is Parliament, which you mentioned, but you didn't mention whether the functions aren't working in Protégé or in Parliament.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Joshua 
I could resolve both problems, they are not related to SPARQL or Protege but to Parliament. it is a triple store so whenever i change values in Prtoege and upload the ontology again to Parliament it was adding the new value and keeping the previous ones

as for the second problem, Protege does can not use the function provided by GeoSPARQL, that is why i used Parliament. the problem was that the resource for the datatype set by Protege is different from that supported by Parliament. had to change it manually

Comment: @loosha I'm glad that this answer helped you find a solution.  However, it sounds like the actual solution was somewhat different than what I'd mentioned.  You should consider writing up your actual solution as an answer and accepting it instead of mine.  It's quite acceptable on StackOverflow to answer your own questions, and this sounds like a case where you might want to do just that.